# Autofac InstancePerLifeTimeScope without BeginLifeTimeScope

Tags: c#, autofac

I've inherited a multi-threaded data processing system that uses AutoFac for Dependency Injection.

Practically all dependencies are defined as `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`, but there are no calls to `container.BeginLifetimeScope()` to open a new scope.

What behaviour should I expect in this situation? I'm guessing one of the following:

1. AutoFac treats all resolution requests as belonging to a single 'global' scope and therefore returns the same instance for every resolution request (behaving like a singleton)
2. AutoFac considers that no scope exists and ignores the InstancePerLifetimeScope and treats every resolution request as transient.

The system is essentially a multi-threaded Windows Service; therefore no HTTP Requests or associated scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use *Autofac* you create a `IContainer` from a `ContainerBuilder`. This `IContainer` inherits from `ILifetimeScope` and it is the global scope, the root of the scope tree, all other scopes will inherits from this scope.

When you resolve something from *Autofac* there is always a scope, if you don't create a child lifetime scope `InstancePerLifetimeScope` is like `SingleInstance`.